# How to put data from an Excel sheet into an API link with multiple parameters and download the PDF using Python?

Tags: python, excel, api, google-docs-api

I am working on a certificate making program in Python. For it, I need to take name, school and roll number from an excel file and put it at the last of an API link which is of Google Docs (I made the structure of the certificate in Google Docs). The names are too much so I used a for loop. The API link when opened in a browser will give me a link which if I open, would download the PDF of the certificate with the respective name of the student.

I tried but cannot find the way to add the names and roll number to the end of the URL, so that the URL is openable. Also, the names have spaces in between them so I have to make the names URL friendly first.
How to add those parameters to URL alongwith using the loop, So that I have a bunch of URLs with parameters from the excel sheet?

```
    import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_excel (r'D:\SciQuest_2020.xlsx')
print (df)

SchDict = {'B01':"DAV Public School Chandrasekharpur",'B02':"DAV Public School Pokhariput",'B05':"ODM Public School",'C01':"Delhi Public School Kalinga",'C02':"St. Joseph's Girls' High School",'C03':"Steward School Cuttack",'K01': "Kendriya Vidyalaya Khurda Road",'K02': "Carmel English Medium School",'K03': "Oneness International School",'K04': "DAV Public School, Khordha"}

url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzYpmxFCPbRp2Wmh_neHunDOUzbh1ji5TkLmHk1GA/exec?data="
datas = []
for i in range(1,4):
    Name = df.iloc[i]["Name"]
    Class = df.iloc[i]["STD"]
    Roll_No = df.iloc[i]["RollNo"]
    Schul = SchDict[Roll_No[0:3]]
    Name.replace(" ","%20")
    newlink = "".join((url, Name, Roll_No, Schul))
```

Comment: _cannot find the right way to do it._ What does that mean, can you be more specific?

Comment: I cannot find a way to do it. The code that I have posted is incomplete and some part of it might be wrong too.

Comment: _I cannot find a way to do it._ Find a way to do **what**?

Comment: To make the certificate making program. The whole thing that I explained earlier.

Comment: I am working on a certificate making program in Python. For it, I need to take name, school and roll number from an excel file and put it at the last of an API link which is of Google Docs (I made the structure of the certificate in Google Docs). The names are too much so I used a for loop. The API link when opened in a browser will give me a link which if I open, would download the PDF of the certificate with the respective name of the student.

Comment: That's just a list of requirements, though, which part is the problem?

Comment: I have edited the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be encoding all the parameters not just Name e.g. the single quote in Joseph's should be %27.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib

df = pd.read_excel("C:/tmp/certs.xlsx")# (r'D:\SciQuest_2020.xlsx')

SchDict = {
    'B01':"DAV Public School Chandrasekharpur",
    'B02':"DAV Public School Pokhariput",
    'B05':"ODM Public School",
    'C01':"Delhi Public School Kalinga",
    'C02':"St. Joseph's Girls' High School",
    'C03':"Steward School Cuttack",
    'K01': "Kendriya Vidyalaya Khurda Road",
    'K02': "Carmel English Medium School",
    'K03': "Oneness International School",
    'K04': "DAV Public School, Khordha"
}
# create log file
f = open("debug.txt", "w")

url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/" + \
      "AKfycbzYpmxFCPbRp2Wmh_neHunDOUzbh1ji5TkLmHk1GA/exec?data="

for i in range(0,10):
    Name = df.iloc[i]["Name"]
    Class = df.iloc[i]["STD"]
    RollNo = df.iloc[i]["RollNo"]
    Schul = SchDict[RollNo[0:3]]
    param = urllib.parse.quote( ''.join((Name, RollNo, Schul)) )
    uri = url + param
    f.write("row {} | {} | {} |\n".format(i,Name,param))

f.close()
print("results written to debug.txt")
```